# windows authentication and individual authentication in one project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 
i just was wondering if I can use windows authentication and individual authentication in one project.

Means I would like to switch pro grammatically during the run time. Is it possible to do that?.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "individual authentication" in this context, but yes. You can choose authentication methods at runtime

Comment: individual authentication means membership auth. so please refer me to an article or video for that. @K.AlanBates